# Passing struct as a parameter to smart contract action

Tags: smart-contract, action, c++

I want to save data in the blockchain table whose format is as below:

```
{
  "docsample": {
    "id": 1,
    "creationDate": "2012-05-16T18:25:43.511Z",
    "contentType": "abc",
    "type": "abc",
    "owner": {
      "name": "abc",
      "certificate": {
        "serialNumber": "abc",
        "issuer": "abc"
      }
    },
    "fingerprint": "abc"
  }
}
```

In my smart contract, I declared `owner` as one struct and `cert` as another. I want to pass this struct as a parameter to action. Smart contract struct are:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] ipdoctable {
                        uint64_t id;
                        time_point_sec createdAt;
                        std::string contentType;
                        std::string type;
                        struct owner;
                        name fingerprint;

                        uint64_t primary_key() const { return fingerprint.value;}
                        };

                        typedef eosio::multi_index<"ipdocs"_n, ipdoctable> ipdoc_index;

                        struct [[eosio::table]] owner{
                                std::string name;
                                struct certificate;
                        };

                        struct [[eosio::table]] certificate{
                                std::string serialNumber;
                                std::string issuer;
                        };
```

And Action is:

```
[[eosio::action]]
 void upsertipdoc(time_point_sec createdAt, std::string contentType, std::string type, struct ownerinfo *owner,name fingerprint) {
      ipdoc_index ipdocs ( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );
      bool found = false;
      for(auto itr = ipdocs.begin(); itr != ipdocs.end() && found!=true; itr++) {
      if(itr->fingerprint == fingerprint) {
         found = true;
         ipdocs.modify(itr, _self, [&]( auto& row ) {
                row.contentType = contentType,
                row.type = type,
                row.owner = owner,
                row.fingerprint = fingerprint;
                });
          }
     }
```

Apologies if any illogical mistake in the code. Not much familiar with C++. Please guide how would I save data in the given manner?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find the solution. I use struct in the struct as follows.

```
struct certificateinfo{
   string serialNumber;
   string issuer;
};

struct ownerinfo{
   string name;
   certificateinfo certificate;
};

struct [[eosio::table]] ipdoctable {
       uint64_t id;
       string creationDate;
       string contentType;
       string type;
       ownerinfo owner;
       name fingerprint;

       uint64_t primary_key() const { return fingerprint.value;}
       };

       typedef eosio::multi_index<"ipdocs"_n, ipdoctable> ipdoc_index;
```

Accept the parameters separately as string instead of struct in the action and set the owner and certificate struct values as follow:

```
[[eosio::action]]
 void upsertipdoc(time_point_sec createdAt, std::string contentType, std::string type, string ownername,string serialNumber,string issuer, name fingerprint) {

      ownerinfo ownerinfo = {ownername, {serialNumber,issuer}};

      ipdoc_index ipdocs ( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );
      bool found = false;
      for(auto itr = ipdocs.begin(); itr != ipdocs.end() && found!=true; itr++) {
      if(itr->fingerprint == fingerprint) {
         found = true;
         ipdocs.modify(itr, _self, [&]( auto& row ) {
                row.contentType = contentType,
                row.type = type,
                row.owner = ownerinfo,
                row.fingerprint = fingerprint;
                });
          }
     }
```

Thank you!